# Select single View drawn on Android canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, draw

I'm new to Android and discover lots of things. But now I'm quite stucked.
I want to make a hexagonal board game, with tiles. I found many tutos and finally decided to draw as mush hexagons as I want to.

I created a 'Hex' class extending from View, add some variables and so on. Here is what I put in my main XML layout:

```
<flocoolb.app6.Hex
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    flocoolb:r="50"
    android:id="@+id/h01"/>
<flocoolb.app6.Hex
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    flocoolb:r="50"
    flocoolb:x="75"
    flocoolb:y="43.30127"
    android:id="@+id/h02"/>
<flocoolb.app6.Hex
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    flocoolb:r="50"
    flocoolb:x="150"
    android:id="@+id/h03"/>
```

r=size, x and y are offsets on canvas.
Here is what I get on my activity:
[Main activity screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avlix.png)

But now I want to select single Hex. For example I want to select to top left one, or the bottom right one. I add OnClickListener on each of them, but actually the size of the view is the whole screen.
For example, if I change the background color of the view, it change that color on the whole screen. Is it possible to have the view limited to the drawn lines?

I hope you will understand what I mean.
Many thanks :)

Comment: I've just succeeded to change the background color of the view. I added a method "changeColor()" in Hex class that change the color, invalidate the view and use requestLayout().
Then inside the "OnClickListener" I get the ID from the View v, get the Hex from this ID, and use the previous method "changeColor()".
That's good! But now my problem is describe in the @wngxao 's answer: the View takes the full screen and therefore, weherever I touch the screen, the selected View is the last in the XML layout

Comment: It may deal with clipping [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Although,I don't understand you very much.But I suggest you to override onTouch Method of your view.And implement your function in onTouch method.

Comment: Each Hex takes the whole screen. I declared 8 hexagons in my XML, the 8 we see on the attached picture. With the color changing inside the OnClickListener, here is what I get : [link](http://i.imgur.com/K1iFuyF.png)

Moreover, whatever Hex I touch, it is the last one declared on the foregroung. Inside the OnClickListener if I write "v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);" they will be invisible from the last to the first in the XML layout.

Here is what I finally would like: [link](http://i.imgur.com/WRgXqge.png)